# Spaces instead of tabs in Eclipse (Galileo 3.52)?

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way in Eclipse (Galileo 3.52) to have it replace tabs with spaces ("soft tabs")?  I've tried two things so far . . .

Windows>Preferences>Editors>Text Editors... check "Insert spaces for tabs"

...and...

Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter->Edit...  "Use Spaces to indent wrapped lines"

(... this forces you to create a new profile to save these settings)

This produces **partial** success - the **first** tab is turned in to spaces but **subsequent** ones are still tabs.  So if I type

*tabtab* 1234

...I end up with...

*spacespacespacespace* **tab** 1234

Comment: It depends on the editor. Are you using the php, html, xml or java editor (or something else?)

Comment: For "... Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style... " I'd assume he is using the Java editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

1. Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter
2. Click on “Show” button (or "Edit") right beside the name of the profile you are using.
3. In the indentantion Tab, change the "Tab Policy" field to "spaces only"
4. Click Ok, and save the profile with the name you want.

Comment: Bingo - I didn't click on the "Tabs Only" dropdown to discover it had a "Spaces Only" option.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could the missing setting be the *Tab policy: Spaces only* combo box in *Preferences >Java > Code Style Formatter > Edit > Indentation* (right above where you changed *Use spaces to indent wrapped lines*)?